# I am trying to change the url for json parsing in my app on every click of option in settings menu

Tags: android

When the code is run it loads news only of india even after selecting another option in the Settings  Menu. Can someone please tell me the error?

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.user.s;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class MainActivity extends ListActivity
{

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url;
   public String servername;


    private  static final  String TAG_ARTICLES="articles";
    private static final String TAG_PUBLISH_DATE = "publish_date";
    private static final String TAG_SOURCE = "source";
    private static final String TAG_SUMMARY = "summary";
    private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
    private static final int RESULT_SETTINGS = 1;
    JSONArray articles = null;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> articleList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        articleList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        ListView lv = getListView();

        // Listview on item click listener



              /*  // Starting single contact activity
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SingleContactActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_PUBLISH_DATE, date);
                in.putExtra(TAG_SOURCE, source);
                in.putExtra(TAG_SUMMARY, desc);
                in.putExtra(TAG_TITLE,ttle);
                startActivity(in);*/



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.action_settings:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, setting.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_SETTINGS);
                break;

        }

        return true;
    }


    private void update() {
        GetContacts weatherTask = new GetContacts();
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplication());
        String location = prefs.getString(getString(R.string.country_preference),
                getString(R.string.country_default));
        if(location.equals("India"))
            url="http://api.feedzilla.com/v1/categories/19/subcategories/888/articles.json?count=10";
        else
           url="http://api.feedzilla.com/v1/categories/19/subcategories/890/articles.json?count=10";
        weatherTask.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        update();
    }

    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

      @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();


            // Showing progress dialog

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Creating service handler class instance

            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    articles = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_ARTICLES);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < articles.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = articles.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PUBLISH_DATE);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_SOURCE);
                        String email = c.getString(TAG_SUMMARY);
                        String ttle = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);

                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put(TAG_PUBLISH_DATE, id);
                        contact.put(TAG_SOURCE, name);
                        contact.put(TAG_SUMMARY, email);
                        contact.put(TAG_TITLE, ttle);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        articleList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, articleList,
                    R.layout.row, new String[]{TAG_PUBLISH_DATE, TAG_SOURCE,
                    TAG_SUMMARY}, new int[]{R.id.publish_date,
                    R.id.src, R.id.summary});

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }



}
```

Settings Activity:

```
package com.example.user.s;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class setting extends PreferenceActivity {
    private static final String COUNTRIES = "countries";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);
    }
}
```

preference.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Country">

        <ListPreference
            android:key="country_preference"
            android:title="@string/country_preference"
            android:summary="Choose your Country"
            android:entries="@array/entries_transport_list_preference"
            android:entryValues="@array/entryvalues_transport_list_preference"

           />

    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

array.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="entries_transport_list_preference">
        <item>India</item>
        <item>China</item>
        <item>Japan</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="entryvalues_transport_list_preference">
        <item>India</item>
        <item>China</item>
        <item>3</item>
    </string-array>``
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call update() in onResume instead onStart

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    update();
}
```